# Adjusting shapes of HTML elements using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to make 9 HTML elements into equal squares within a div class using CSS. However, they are rectangular when the measurements suggest they should be squares.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class= "gameboard">
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="playerMove('button1')"/><input type="button" id="button2" onclick="playerMove('button2')"/><input type="button" id="button3" onclick="playerMove('button3')"/>
<input type="button" id="button4" onclick="playerMove('button4')"/><input type="button" id="button5" onclick="playerMove('button5')"/><input type="button" id="button6" onclick="playerMove('button6')"/>
<input type="button" id="button7" onclick="playerMove('button7')"/><input type="button" id="button8" onclick="playerMove('button8')"/><input type="button" id="button9" onclick="playerMove('button9')"/>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.gameboard {

    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 70px;

}
```

Comment: This is your code in a JSfiddle and I see squares there...
https://jsfiddle.net/9a4yozoq/

Comment: Isn't a square a rectangle anyway?

Comment: Do you want to have a 3x3 view?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting their `margin` and `padding` to 0 and see if it works.